# Issue while importing updated database on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm doing an application on Visual Studio using an SQL Server database, the application is almost complete but I did a few changes on the database (added and deleted some rows) but when I'm trying to do the Schema Comparison to update the database on Visual Studio it doesn't let me choose a project as the target.
According to what I've found, it should show the project I'm working on, but instead I have this:

[image]

Comment: do you have the project open?  It has to be opened to be recognized in this dialog box

Comment: Yes it is open, I am doing it FROM the project.

Comment: actually I think I did run into this in the past too, try setting the project as the source and then the Database as the target, then once you are in the compare window you can hit the reverse button (two arrows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use directly database comparison and you will get the difference anyways

Comment: I don't understand, you're saying I should compare the database with itself?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to do it the other way round? So if you want to compare changes with the database so you can update the database (your target schema) you should be clicking 'Database' and doing it that way. That will show you the differences, which you can then choose to propagate to the database.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833202(v=vs.100).aspx#CompareTheTwoSchemas) for more info.

Comment: It doesn't work either way, it shows the same thing.

Comment: @TammyMoscoso - I'm not sure I understand your comment. Doing it this way you're not trying to using the 'Project' drop down as it sounds like you're not trying to set that as your target schema anyway. If your target schema is the DB then use the DB settings.